# Do AWS DynamoDb streams consume the table's read capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am reading into [DynamoDb](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) and [DynamoDb Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and I cannot find a place where is says whether having a DynamoDb stream is consuming read capacity from the stream's table.

I am aware that Streams have their own capacity units that that cost (see the first link I posted), but I also want to know whether I should increase my table's read capacity after I enable a stream for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using DynamoDB Streams won't throttle/exhaust your read capacity.

In essence, DynamoDB Streams are "transactional logs" for DynamoDB tables.

You pay separataley for Read Capacity Units (RCUs) and [Read Request Units](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) (bottom of the page).

Comment: That was my assumption as well, I was surprised to not find a specific place in the AWS docs saying that. Is there?

Comment: I couldn't find anything explicitly saying it, but if you take a second look, the prices per unit are different and also, for the RCUs you pay on hourly basis, as for the Streams read units you pay on used unit.

Answer (score 1):

No, DynamoDB streams will never consume Read capacity units from your table. You can consider this as a transaction log enabled on top of your DynamoDB table which can be used to capture every modification to items in the table.